# What does VARCHAR(20*4) mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Referring to this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-redshift.html

They list some mappings as:

VARCHAR(20*4)
VARCHAR(size*4)

I assume they didn't mean VARCHAR(80) for 20*4 or they would have put that?

Any insights would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe they want to put in 20 things of length 4?

Comment: That means 4 is the **maximum bytes per character**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappings are like:

```
MySql          Redshift
-------------  ---------------
VARCHAR(size)  VARCHAR(size*4)
```

meaning that if you have `VARCHAR(20)` in MySql you need `VARCHAR(80)` in Redshift.

The reason is that in Redshift `VARCHAR(x)` means "x bytes" - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html